# How to connect to AWS ec2 Instance from Chromebook Pixel

Tags: amazon-web-services, chromebook

I have a laptop running ChromeOS. I'm looking to do some work with Python on AWS but I'm not entirely certain how to SSH to the box. If anyone can give me details on how to connect I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the IP address and an SSH client such as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo ?

Comment: Yes. I can get that information. I haven't assigned an IP to it but I can get one. I can also just use the public name that they assign I believe.

Comment: If it's a domain name like xx.com or xx.net, you can. If it's "InstanceEC214", you can't. Try downloading that plugin for chrome and see if you can SSH into the server that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Chromebook:

1. Download your private key, for example: `myKey.pem`.
2. Connect to your EC2 instance from **crosh**. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start it, then:

   ```
   crosh>ssh
   ssh>user your-user
   ssh>host your-host
   ssh>key your-key
   ssh>connect
   ```

   *your-user* is either:

   - `ubuntu` if your instance is Ubuntu, or
   - `ec2-user` if your instance is of Amazon AMI type.

   *your-host* is a string like this: ec2-number-numbers-numbers-numbers.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. You'll find that in your AWS console under **Running instances**, under **Public DNS**.

   *your-key* is `myKey` if you downloaded it like `myKey.pem`.
3. Once you are connected to your instance you can work from there (from **crosh**); or you could make a public key from your private key, in order to connect using [secure shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) (Secure shell saves your user, host, and keys so you don't have to repeat 'em every time)
4. Make your public key.
   On any Linux machine where you have your private `myKey.pem`, run this:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -y -f myKey.pem > myKey.pub
   ```
5. Now install secure shell on your chromebook.

   Run it.
   Fill user and host.
   On **Identity** click **Import...**, and select BOTH miKey.pem and miKey.pub.
   Click **[ENTER] Connect** and you're done.

Sources: [Connecting to EC2 from Chrome’s Secure Shell using only a PEM file](http://www.mattburns.co.uk/blog/2012/11/15/connecting-to-ec2-from-chromes-secure-shell-using-only-a-pem-file/)

Comment: Note you can no longer use `ssh` through `crosh` in Chrome OS anymore. They recommend a chrome extension instead.

Comment: Indeed, ssh is no longer implemented by crosh, meaning it's now impossible to spin up, and connect to, an ec2 instance with only a Chromebook.